# Sorting string of characters in assembly

Tags: assembly

i'm trying to figure out how to sort the characters in my program. Some reason I think my sort is messing up, because when i put it in the program just crashes, but when its not in the program it runs just fine.

Right now here's the cpp file with the sorting parameter:

```
    extern "C" void Sort (char [] [11], char [], double [], long);
```

and here's my sorting in assembly

```
_Sort proc
    mov eax, [esp + 8]
    cmp eax, 1
    jle L1
    push ebp

    mov ebp, esp
    mov edx, 1
    imul edx, Row
    mov Count, edx

    imul edx, Column
    push edx 
    cld

L1:
    call _comp
    cmp ebx, 1
    jz L1
    add esp, 4
    pop ebp
L2:
    ret
_Sort endp

_Comp Proc
    mov edx, 0
    mov Count, 0;

L3:
    mov edi, offset _pArray1
    mov esi, pArray
    add esi, edx
    mov ecx, Column
    rep movsb

    add edx, Column
    inc Count
    mov edi, offset _pArray2
    mov ecx, Column
    rep movsb

    mov edi, offset _pArray1
    mov esi, offset _pArray2
    mov ecx, Column
    repz cmpsb

    jge L4
    call _Switch
    mov ebx, 1
    jmp L5
L4:
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, Done
    sub eax, Column
    cmp edx, eax
    jz L5
    jmp L3

L5:
    ret

_Comp endp

_Switch proc

    mov edi, pArray
    add edi, edx
    sub edi, Column
    mov esi, offset _pArray2

    mov ecx, Column
    rep movsb
    mov esi, offset _pArray1
    mov ecx, Column
    rep movsb

    mov esi, [ebp + 12]
    add esi, Count
    dec esi

    mov cl, [esi]
    xchg cl, [esi +1]
    mov [esi], cl

    ret

_Switch endp
```

Comment: Please provide the names for the function parameters, and for how `Row`, `Count` etc are defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pointing out only a few problems which are obvious from reading your code, so I haven't looked much farther, especially as you use variables which you are neither showing nor seeming to initialize.

First the stack when the function is called:

```
 sp+ 0 = caller return address
 sp+ 4 = char [] [11]
 sp+ 8 = char []
 sp+ c = double []
 sp+10 = long
```

So you start your code and the first thing you check is wether the pointer `char []` equals 1. I guess this is not what you intended.

```
mov eax, [esp + 8]
cmp eax, 1
```

If this is true, which probably doesn't happen, but it could be null then you execute this code:

```
L1:
call _comp   ; we call _comp which uses ebp from the parent function, so it is to be considered not as initialzed *BAM*
cmp ebx, 1   ; why should ebx be 1? You never initilized it, but maybe it is a random value frmo the caller?
jz L1
add esp, 4   ; you are now corrupting the stack
pop ebp      ; corrupting it even more

L2:
ret          ; and jump back to  where char[] points to. *BAM*
```

Now assume the branch was not taken, we continue here:

```
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp     ; setup the stackframe, which is ok.

    mov edx, 1
    imul edx, Row    ; Where does Row com from? Is it initlized? Where?
    mov Count, edx   ; Save the value in Count, but...

    imul edx, Column
    push edx         ; ?
    cld

L1:
    call _comp      ; ... here we call _comp which first instruction is, to initialize Count again.

....
```

So I would recommend to rethink this code, add comments so you know what it is supposed to do, and run it in a debugger to check if it is doing what you think it should do.